# Cache a CSV file on Java application server

Tags: java, parsing, caching

I have an application server in Java which requires parsing a CSV file.  Is there any way by which I could increase the performance, as the program requires parsing the CSV file for each new connection.

The CSV file is static, so I was thinking about caching it in the main memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why cache the csv in memory? Cache the parsed result in memory. Don't know what you are parsing it to, but create a class that represents a record. Make that class immutable, and then cache in E.g. a List or Map if you want fast access to certain records.

Answer (score 1):

The file will be cached by the OS in memory for you if you read it re-read the file repeatedly.  I suggest you cache the parsed data.  You can check the modification data (and possibly the length) of the file and re-parse it only if it has changed.